# How do I automatically fire a (remote) stored procedure in SQL Server when connecting to a remote server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

The specific issue is that I want a SQL Server to connect to an Oracle database and the Oracle database has a Virtual Private Database configured.  I need to execute a static stored procedure to enable the VPD to see data.  How can I configure SQL Server to fire a stored procedure upon connecting to a remote database?  I figure if I can fire a local stored procedure, I can put the remote stored procedure call inside of that.  The key is, I need the SQL Server to fire this as soon as it is done connecting to the remote database and before it tries to pass any other queries to it.  I'm trying to avoid making the applications do it explicitly.

Comment: There is no configurable "hook" that you can invoke to run just after SQL Server connects remotely. The best thing you could manage is to create a logon trigger on SQL Server itself that fires up the remote connection before the application even does anything, but that's fraught with peril -- a malfunctioning logon trigger can prevent connecting by anyone, even admins -- so such a trigger would have to be carefully written to only activate for particular credentials/app names.

Comment: I was hoping it was that my google-fu was weak, but my fear was that it is simply impossible.  If I were to call the Oracle stored procedure during SQL Server login, how many concurrent connections can SQL Server create to Oracle at once (per session)?  Can it close the connection while the SQL Server session is active?

Comment: It depends on the provider used. For SQL Server remote connections, it will use connection pooling -- that is, only as many connections will be used as there are concurrent sessions using them, and the physical connections "linger" even after clients have stopped using them (they definitely don't disappear with the SQL session). For generic providers and Oracle in particular, no idea. I would *imagine* it uses the same kind of logic, but you'd really have to test. No guarantees on this behavior are documented and AFAIK you can't even configure things like the maximum lifetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does not offer a solution to my problem.
However, you can setup the service account to have a logon trigger to execute what is needed.

```
Create Trigger My_User.Logon_Trigger_Name
AFTER LOGON
ON SCHEMA 
WHEN (USER = 'MY_USER')
BEGIN
    --Do Stuff Here.
    NULL;
EXCEPTION    
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        NULL;  --Consume errors so you can still log on.
END;
```